# how to add and remove jquery tabs dynamically?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tabs

I have an aspx page on which I have 2 static jquery tabs.Upon clicking on a button avaiable on one of these tabs,I would like to add a new tab dynamically,which gets its content loaded from another aspx page.I've also tried with the following sample

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/manipulation.html

I've downloaded jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom zip file and tried to add the above page with the relevant script,css files to my asp.net website and run,but it does not seem to work.Also I do not want to have a dialog opening and asking the user to enter the tab title as in the above sample.

Please could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone repair the link?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have you tried using the [add method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-add) of the tabs?

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
$('#tabs-1 button').click(function(){
    tabs.tabs('add','/url_for_tab/','New tab');
});
```

**Update --** As of jQuery UI 1.9 the add remove methods have been deprecated and in jQuery UI 1.10 they have been removed.

The correct way to do this for remote (ajax) content tabs now is:

```
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
$( "<li><a href='/url_for_tab/'>New Tab</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
```

And for when you already have the content:

```
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
$( "<li><a href='#newtab'>New Tab</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
$( "<div id='newtab'><p>New Content</p></div>" ).appendTo( tabs );
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
```

Comment: The add and remove methods have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.9, and removed in 1.10. Use the refresh method instead. [jQuery upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method)

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the "refresh" method to work and had to resort to tabs.tabs("destroy"); tabs.tabs(); - I guess that this is what the refresh method should do.  jQuery 1.7.2, jQueryUI 1.8.13 (Maybe I should update those)

Comment: Why deprecate something that is working perfectly well, and is easy to use and replace it with a method that is more difficult?  I'm currently upgrading an old site from jQuery 1.4 to 2.1.4, and it has been far from straightforward...  the main difficulties have been all the deprecated jQuery functions!

Comment: @Teevus  I concur.  I am still puzzled as to why the tab methods were removed.  They were very clear and easy to use.  The new approach is hideous!

Answer (score 1):

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var tabber = createMainTab();
tabber.setAttribute("id","tabber")
var mainHelper = createTabHelper();
var testH = createTabHelperElement("Test tab",tabber);
var testTab = createTab(testH);
tabber.appendChild(mainHelper);

mainHelper.appendChild(testH);
tabber.appendChild(testTab);

main.appendChild(tabber);
$(tabber).tabs();

function createMainTab(){
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    mainDiv.setAttribute("class","ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");
    mainDiv.style.height="100%";
    mainDiv.onk_initialised = false;
    return mainDiv;
}
function createTabHelper(){
    var mainUl = document.createElement("ul");
    mainUl.setAttribute("class","ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all");
    return mainUl;
}
function createTabHelperElement(name,mainTab){
    var mainLi = document.createElement("li");
    var active = !mainTab.onk_initialised;
    mainTab.onk_initialised=true;
    if(active){
        mainLi.setAttribute("class","ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active");
    }else{
        mainLi.setAttribute("class","ui-state-default ui-corner-top");
    }
    mainLi.onk_createdActive = active;
    mainLi.onk_id = "tab_"+cache;
    var oLink = document.createElement("a");
    oLink.setAttribute("href","#tab_"+cache);
    oLink.innerHTML = name;
    mainLi.appendChild(oLink);
    cache++;
    return mainLi;
}
function createTab(tabHelper){
    var tabDiv = document.createElement("div");
    if(tabHelper.onk_createdActive){
        tabDiv.setAttribute("class","ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
    }else{
        tabDiv.setAttribute("class","ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide");
    }
    tabDiv.setAttribute("id",tabHelper.onk_id);
    return tabDiv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also adding tabs dynamically.

```
mytabs.tabs('add', '/url_for_tab/', 'New tab title');
```

works in getting that new tab added. in my case its a dynamic jsp file

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get two other jQuery UI Widgets: Dialog and Position.

I had the same issue: downloaded the demo, and manipulate.html did not work. In my case, it was throwing an error on page load:

```
$("#dialog").dialog is not a function
   close: function() {
```

And the page had 404s:
    jquery.ui.position.js
    jquery.ui.dialog.js

So, the page had dependencies that were unexpected, and not included in my custom download.
I went back and got another custom download from http://jqueryui.com/download

Once the demo could resolve jquery.ui.dialog.js it worked, because the dialog function existed:

```
typeof $("#dialog").dialog
"function"
```