# Adding a LI Dynamically , JQuery tabs not styling correctly

Tags: jquery, tabs

So what I am doing is dynamically adding items to and UL, no problem there. but what I want to do with use jquery tabs to create tabs. But the tabs don't seem to style 100% correctly. I am assuming it has something to do with how I am inserting my li and what is rendering for a normal li. Anyway here is my code. I took out some of the dynamic part just to try to get it inserting and it still doesn't render correctly.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul >
      <li><a href="#LinkSection">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#LinkSection">b</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div>
    <div id="LinkSection">
        Test Data

    </div>



   <script type="text/javascript">

$('#tabs').tabs(
       {

           fx: { opacity: 'toggle' },
           select: function (event, ui) {
               jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(this).height());
               jQuery(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
           },
           show: function (event, ui) {
               jQuery(this).css('height', 'auto');
               jQuery(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
           }

       }
       );
function CreateTabs() {

               for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {            
                   $('#tabs ul').append(
                    $('<li>').append(
                    $('<a>').attr('href', '#LinkSection').append(
                    $('<span>').attr('class', 'tab').append("Message center")
                        )));

               }

           }
</script>
```

I have also tried inserting a li like this but the same result

```
 $("#tabs ul").append('<li><a href="#LinkSection">c</a></li>');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add and remove jquery tabs dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416547/how-to-add-and-remove-jquery-tabs-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the issue was not with this code but my json call. i did not include this in the initial code because i didn't think it would make a difference how i was getting the list but it did. Seems i left out the async:false and that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refresh the tabs like below:

```
$("#tabs ul").append('<li><a href="#LinkSection">c</a></li>');
$('#tabs').tabs("refresh");
```

You can check the jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/beroza/ryppd5dq/